# Append to Dataframe Output from Pool (multiprocessing)

Tags: python, dataframe, beautifulsoup, multiprocessing

I am trying to save the url and price data of into a data frame so to save the file in Excel/csv, but I am finding difficulties as I am new to the subject.

```
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from multiprocessing import Pool
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()

def get_price(url):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}).content, "html.parser")
    data = json.loads(soup.find_all('script', {'type': 'application/ld+json'})[-1].get_text())
    return url, int(data['offers']['price'])

if __name__ == '__main__':

    urls = ['https://www.tiffany.co.uk/jewelry/necklaces-pendants/tiffany-hardwear-graduated-link-necklace-63008966/',
            'https://www.tiffany.co.uk/jewelry/necklaces-pendants/tiffany-t-smile-pendant-35189459/',]

    with Pool(processes=4) as pool:
        for url, price in pool.imap_unordered(get_price, urls):
                df = df.append(price)
```

I continue to get "TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'int'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid", the url type is string and price is int. Anyone knows how to solve this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

i think using dictionary has a better performance as a first step, and you cannot append integers to pandas DataFrame.
rest is here in the code

```
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from multiprocessing import Pool
import pandas as pd

data = {'offers_price':[]}  #e.x key

def get_price(url):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}).content, "html.parser")
    data = json.loads(soup.find_all('script', {'type': 'application/ld+json'})[-1].get_text())
    return url, int(data['offers']['price'])

if __name__ == '__main__':

    urls = ['https://www.tiffany.co.uk/jewelry/necklaces-pendants/tiffany-hardwear-graduated-link-necklace-63008966/',
            'https://www.tiffany.co.uk/jewelry/necklaces-pendants/tiffany-t-smile-pendant-35189459/',]

    with Pool(processes=4) as pool:
        for url, price in pool.imap_unordered(get_price, urls):
            data['offers_price'].append(price) #updating the dict
    df = pd.DataFrame(data) #finally creating a df
```